# querySelector returning null in Casperjs

Tags: javascript, casperjs, selectors-api

I'm using Casperjs to scrape a website, and am trying to extract a specific div that contains a list. A simplified version of the page I'm scraping would be:

```
<div id="col1" style="margin-top: 1px; ">
    <div class="portlet_my_classes" id="my_classes">
        <div class="eclass_list">
            <ul>
                <li>First item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My casper script is as follows:

```
var casper = require('casper').create()

var classes = []

function getClasses() {
    var classes = document.querySelector(".eclass_list")
    return Array.prototype.map.call(classes, function(e) {
        return e.textContent
    })
}

casper.start('https://redacted', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
    this.fill('form[action="/do/account/login"]', {login: "redacted", password: "redacted"}, true)
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo(this.getHTML())
})

casper.thenOpen('https://redacted', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle())
    this.echo(this.getHTML())
    this.echo(this.evaluate(getClasses))
    this.echo(this.exists(".eclass_list"))
    require('utils').dump(this.getElementInfo(".eclass_list"))
    classes = this.evaluate(getClasses)
})

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo(classes).exit()
});
```

`this.exists(".eclass_list")` returns true, but classes is always null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.querySelector(".eclass_list")` in the `getClasses` function will only return the first element that has this class, not as an array but as an element. So the subsequent `Array.prototype.map` call on a DOM element will fail, because a DOM element doesn't have a `length` property and cannot be interpreted as an array. Since there is an exception (`SyntaxError: Illegal return statement` in Chrome) inside the page context, the return value will be `null`.

What you want is `document.querySelectorAll(".eclass_list")`.

If you would have added the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events, you would have seen the problem.